# PHP - find value in array 3D

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have data something like this:

```
array("1"=>(array("UID"=>"5321", array("1"=>"age", "2"=>"gender", "3"=>"location")),
      "2"=>(array("UID"=>"3213", array("1"=>"location", "2"=>"gender")),
      "3"=>(array("UID"=>"4444", array("1"=>"application", "2"=>"gender"))
     );
```

so, if I search by "age", the result is `array("1"=>"5321")`

if I search by "gender", the result is `array("1"=>"5321", "2"=>"3213", "3"=>"4444")`

basically I want to find who has specific value in php, I need a hand to solve this.

Thanks for your time :)

EDIT, here's my snip:

```
$arr = array("1"=>(array("UID"=>"5321", array("1"=>"age", "2"=>"gender", "3"=>"location"))),
      "2"=>(array("UID"=>"3213", array("1"=>"location", "2"=>"gender"))),
      "3"=>(array("UID"=>"4444", array("1"=>"application", "2"=>"gender")))
     );
     
 $find = "age";
 $storedArr = false;
 foreach($arr as $key=>$arrValue){
    if(in_array($find, $arrValue)){
        if(!$storedArr)
            $storedArr = array("1"=>$arrValue["UID"]);
        else
            array_push($storedArr, $arrValue["UID"]);
    }
 }
 print_r($storedArr);
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Your array structure does not seem right.

Comment: Give me some minutes, I will edit it

Comment: done, I can't access the value attributes of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search value is one level below with index 0. In my code this is $subArr[0].

```
$arr = array(
  "1"=>(array("UID"=>"5321", array("1"=>"age", "2"=>"gender", "3"=>"location"))),
  "2"=>(array("UID"=>"3213", array("1"=>"location", "2"=>"gender"))),
  "3"=>(array("UID"=>"4444", array("1"=>"application", "2"=>"gender")))
);

$find = "gender";
$storedArr = [];
foreach($arr as $id => $subArr){
  if(in_array($find, $subArr[0])){
    $storedArr[$id] = $subArr['UID'];
  }
}
var_export($storedArr);
//array ( 1 => '5321', 2 => '3213', 3 => '4444', )
```

Comment: So, array after "UID" key will be indexed as zero? I am doing this because on my system, we have grid (array start with 1), otherwise they didn't read it as grid

Comment: Yes, if a numeric key does not yet exist, arrays in PHP are indexed from 0. The key 'UID' does not count because it is not a numeric key.

Comment: it is something that I never knew before, thank you very much